# How can I detect language of text using lua script

Tags: lua, detect

How can I detect the language of text using lua script? 
For example I have a document which is in JapaneseUTF8. I want to parse it and identify that this document belongs to Japanese.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for existing libraries/tools for this or are you asking how you would go about doing this from an algorithmic/etc. perspective?

Comment: if any existing libraries are then it is fine, I will use it. Actually I am new to Lua script, so just wanted to know all possibilities to accomplish this.

Comment: The "how to do this" isn't a lua question. That's a language detection question. Whether there is a lua library for tools that do this detection is a lua question. That's why I asked for the clarification.

Comment: Can you please let me know, is there any lua libraries are available to achieve this?

Comment: I don't know of any offhand but this isn't a field I've ever looked into.

Comment: There are [several](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification) open-source libraries, you can try to adapt one for Lua.